# How can I check part of a string for if else statements in C?

Tags: string

I am scanning user input as a string to get a month (user inputs March and month = 3), and I am using if else statements to check which month was input.

```
if (user_input[0] == 'J' && user_input [1] == 'a' && user_input[2] == 'n' 
&& user_input[3] == 'u' && user_input[4] == 'a' && user_input[5] == 'r' 
&& user_input[6] == 'y')
```

Is how i'm checking for January. Is there any way to test this without typing all that out?

like

```
user_input[0-6] == 'January'
```

thanks

Comment: Use `strncmp()` when using char arrays or string is not null terminated or `strcmp()` when string is null terminated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use for loop.Create a switch case state.If you didn't understand I can write the code for you but i prefer you to work yourself with your code except some help